# Select points within a circular area in Mathematica

Tags: select, wolfram-mathematica, conditional-statements

Please consider :

```
dalist = {{9, 6}, {5, 6}, {6, 0}, {0, 5}, {10, 8}, {1, 2}, {10, 4}, {1, 1}, {7, 7}, 
          {6, 8}, {5, 3}, {6, 10}, {7, 4}, {1, 8}, {10, 0}, {10, 7}, {6, 3}, {4, 0}, 
           {9, 2}, {4, 7}, {1, 6}, {10, 8}, {7, 8}, {0, 10}, {3, 4}, {0, 0}, {8, 5}, 
           {4, 5}, {6,0}, {2, 9}, {2, 4}, {8, 4}, {7, 4}, {3, 6}, {7, 10}, {1, 10}, 
           {1, 4}, {8, 0}, {8, 9}, {5, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 9}, {3, 1}, {0, 6}, {10, 3}, 
           {9, 6}, {8, 7}, {7, 6}, {7, 3}, {8, 9}};

frameCenter = {5, 5};

criticalRadius = 2;

Graphics[{
          White, EdgeForm[Thick], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}], Black,
          Point /@ dalist,
          Circle[frameCenter, 2]}];
```

[image]

I would like to create a test to go over dalist and reject the points that are located within or on a certain radius from the frameCenter as illustrated above. I have done that in the past with a rectangular zone but am puzzled on how to do so with a circular area

Comment: All the answers so far will do. If you ever feel the need to test whether points lie in more complex polygons you might want to look at this mathgroup discussion: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/7bf0c7c21b8d916a/c1bbce770899082f

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will be pretty efficient:

```
In[82]:= 
Pick[dalist,UnitStep[criticalRadius^2-Total[(Transpose[dalist]-frameCenter)^2]],0]

Out[82]= 
{{6,0},{10,8},{10,4},{1,1},{6,10},{10,0},{10,7},{4,0},{10,8},
{0,10},{0,0},{6,0},{7,10},{1,10},{8,0},{0,6},{10,3}}
```

Alternatively,

```
In[86]:= Select[dalist, EuclideanDistance[#, frameCenter] > criticalRadius &]

Out[86]= {{6, 0}, {10, 8}, {10, 4}, {1, 1}, {6, 10}, {10, 0}, {10, 7}, {4, 0}, 
 {10, 8}, {0, 10}, {0, 0}, {6, 0}, {7, 10}, {1, 10}, {8, 0}, {0, 6}, {10, 3}}
```

Answer (score 7):

Nearest can be useful for such purposes as finding every set member in some radius of a given point. One uses the less-than-well-documented form of third argument that allows a pair denoting {max number, max distance}. We allow in this case as many as will fit inside the max radius, so the max number is just set to infinity.

```
In[9]:= DeleteCases[dalist, 
 Alternatives @@ 
  Nearest[dalist, frameCenter, {Infinity, criticalRadius}]]

Out[9]= {{9, 6}, {6, 0}, {0, 5}, {10, 8}, {1, 2}, {10, 4}, {1, 1}, {7,
   7}, {6, 8}, {6, 10}, {7, 4}, {1, 8}, {10, 0}, {10, 7}, {6, 3}, {4, 
  0}, {9, 2}, {4, 7}, {1, 6}, {10, 8}, {7, 8}, {0, 10}, {3, 4}, {0, 
  0}, {8, 5}, {6, 0}, {2, 9}, {2, 4}, {8, 4}, {7, 4}, {3, 6}, {7, 
  10}, {1, 10}, {1, 4}, {8, 0}, {8, 9}, {2, 5}, {2, 9}, {3, 1}, {0, 
  6}, {10, 3}, {9, 6}, {8, 7}, {7, 6}, {7, 3}, {8, 9}}
```

--- edit ---

Regarding the complexity of DeleteCases with pattern-free Alternatives, if the input size is n and the set of alternatives has m elements, then it is O(n+m) rather than O(n*m). This as of version 8 of Mathematica.

The examples below will bear out this claim. We start with 10^5 elements and delete around 18000 of them. Takes .17 seconds. We then use 10x as many elements, and remove more than 10x as many (so n and m both go up by a factor of 10 or more). Total time is 1.6 seconds, or a factor of around 10 bigger.

```
In[90]:= dalist5 = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {10^5, 2}];
criticalRadius5 = 5;
Timing[rest5 = 
   DeleteCases[dalist5, 
    Alternatives @@ (closest5 = 
       Nearest[dalist5, {0, 0}, {Infinity, criticalRadius5}])];]
Length[closest5]

Out[92]= {0.17, Null}

Out[93]= 18443

In[94]:= dalist6 = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {10^6, 2}];
criticalRadius6 = 6;
Timing[rest6 = 
   DeleteCases[dalist6, 
    Alternatives @@ (closest6 = 
       Nearest[dalist6, {0, 0}, {Infinity, criticalRadius6}])];]
Length[closest6]

Out[96]= {1.61, Null}

Out[97]= 256465
```

-- end edit ---

Daniel Lichtlau

Comment: +1 for revealing this Nearest syntax. _less-than-well_ might that mean _not_?

Comment: @Sjoerd Not quite not. See tutorial/UsingNearest sixth usage syntax. I will not be surprised if this obscure bit of documentation migrates to the reference page for Nearest.

Comment: I must mention that `DeleteCases` - `Alternatives` based solutions generally have  `m*n` asymptotic complexity, where `m` is the size of the list, and `n` is a number of cases in `Alternatives` (the fact that is a bit hidden by the syntax), and this case is no exception. This will matter for larger lists. This is not to detract from the usefulness of the `Nearest` function.

Comment: @Daniel Interesting! I tested in M7 (I don't have M8 on this laptop), and it is `m*n`. So, I am led to conclusion that the pattern-matcher must have been revised for M8 with regards to `Alternatives`, which probably now is doing something like hashing (in the spirit of `Dispatch`) for non-pattern cases. Is this guess correct?

Comment: @Leonid Correct idea but not for pattern matcher. Cases and DeleteCases were optimized for when the second argument is pattern free. They work in the manner you suggest though: (1) Hash the alternatives (2) Look up each element in the hash table. If there (or not, in DeleteCases) then Sow it. (3) (As in every good morality play:) Reap what you sowed. This was my contribution of Sept 9, 2009 (so I can say I did at least one useful thing that month).

Comment: @Leonid See also: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Sep/msg00342.html

Comment: @Daniel  It seemed familiar - and, sure enough, I found myself on that thread (other branch: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/86dfd51e4d51d2c). I probably forgot about your comment there on the development kernel. I had two contributions there, and the more concise (and perhaps a faster one) is `unsortedComplement[x_, y_] := x /. Dispatch[Thread[Union[y] -> Sequence[]]];`. I can not test now, but from your numbers in that post, I expect a built-in for M8 to beat it 2-3 times. But that is not too bad for a top-level code (my version), I guess.

Comment: @Daniel In any case, thanks a lot, this is a good news and a very valuable piece of information. And I like your comment on morality plays.

Answer (score 1):

Easy - Just use the center of the circle. From that (using Pythagoras theorem) calculate the distance from that centre. Compare that to the radius. Is less than or equal to the radius then it is inside the circle. Otherwise outside.

Comment: As an aside - You can use this method to compute PI. See the monte carlo method for pi (Google it is interested)

Comment: And the tag `Mathematica` is not `math`